Aura framework: portal section embed standard components
I am developing on a Aura Framework site and am wanting to modify some CSS to make a standard report summary component span the entire page, compared to being cut off as below, where we want to utilize the highlighted in red section:

Ive tried a few things, such as an LWC wrapper, where I can get the style fit I want, but I am unable to drop a component into it.
Ive tried aura wrapper, but also unable to drop a component into it.
Any insight on how I can do this?  The section styling limits me to 400px for height.
I've also tried custom themes, but the section styling still overrides the height.
